# Python, index out of range, list

Tags: python, list

I need to change the number with the highest index and the number with the lowest index between each other in the entered line, but an error pops out

Error:

```
    list2[0], list2[len1] = list2[len1], list2[0]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Code:

```
list1 = input("Введите список: ")
list2 = list1.split()
len1 = int(len(list2))
list2[0], list2[len1] = list2[len1], list2[0]
print(list2)
```

How can this be fixed?

Comment: since indexing starts with ``0`` the last item of a list is ``l[len(l) -1]`` or just ``l[-1]``

Answer (score 2, accepted):

List are indexing from 0. If your list contains 4 elements, the length is 4 but the last index is 3 (4 - 1).

```
list1 = input("Введите список: ")
list2 = list1.split()
len1 = int(len(list2)) - 1  # <- HERE
list2[0], list2[len1] = list2[len1], list2[0]
print(list2)
```

Answer (score 3):

Use index `[-1]` instead of `len(list2)-1` to get the last element:

```
list1 = input("Введите список: ").split()
list1[0], list1[-1] = list1[-1], list1[0]
print(list1)
```

Comment: @369 This is the correct answer! No need to know the length of the list at all, though you may want to check it's non-empty!

Answer (score 1):

The indexing is always 0 - length-1.

So if you take the list value at length, it will be out of the aforementioned index range.

Another thing I would like to point out is that your variable names are really very confusing. It's a small code, however for bigger projects, when you'll have to debug this, it will be a serious pain for you.

However, this should work

```
ip = input("Введите список: ")
list1 = ip.split(" ")
len1 = int(len(list1))
list1[0], list1[len1-1] = list1[len1-1], list1[0]
print(list1)
```

Answer (score 1):

As the Error states, the index for the "list2[len1]" is out of range.

Since len() method in python returns the actual length of the list, whereas the indexing of list starts with 0th position

for the above code, you can try doing this:

```
list2[0], list2[len1-1] = list2[len1-1], list2[0]
```